# Удаление COM объекта c#

Tags: c#, .net, com

Использую для своего приложения MVC парсер для word документа. Я заметил что после того как парсер отработает, документ остаётся в памяти. 
Использовал метод :

```
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Doc);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MSWord);
```

но он не помогает, объект всё ещё висит в памяти.
Как удалить объект типа `System.__COMObject` из памяти?

Проблемные строки:

```
Word.Application MSWord = new Word.Application();

Word.Document Doc = MSWord.Documents.Open(urlDocMenu, ConfirmConversions: true);
```

После этих строк появляется объект в памяти и я не знаю как его удалить

Comment: А не могли бы вы предоставить минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему? (И да, откуда вы знаете, что объект ещё жив?)

Comment: @VladD Да, простите, описание проблемы правил. А про объект я узнал банально зайдя в Диспетчер задач, увидев там штуки 4 вордовских процессов

Comment: А, становится понятнее. А если сделать-таки Marshal.ReleaseComObject и подождать ничего не делая? Не помню сколько, минуту или пять, чтобы COM-сервер умер.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По-моему, код может быть примерно таким:

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordApp.Visible = true;
var doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(urlDocMenu);
...
doc.Close();
wordApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Все верно, для закрытия Word служит метод Quit. На одну минуту не успел ответить =)

Comment: все гениальное просто =) простите за флуд

Answer (score 2):

Согласно информации из [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Val)` гарантированно уберет все ссылки и позволит закрыться объекту.

Answer (score 0):

По моему `app.Quit()` работает корректно, но можно еще и попробовать поставить значение `app = null` потом вызвать сборщика мусора `GC.Collect()`.

Comment: Нет. Вы не может надеяться, что сборщик мусора подчистит за вами, `GC.Collect()` ничего не гарантирует. Кроме того, это бесцельное расходование ресурсов: сборщику мусора нужно много труда, чтобы найти одну-единственную отпущенную вами ссылку. Кроме того, это сбивает автонастройку сборщика мусора и ухудшает производительность программы. И всё это — чтобы не вызвать один раз `Quit`?